# Unable to send an audio file to browser for streaming; only a few bytes are received (Content-Size: 0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I try to send an audio file to the browser for immediate playback. The payload is recognized as audio and the media player shows up. But unfortunately the network tab of the debug tools show that only a few bytes are transmitted and the header reports a content size of 0.

I've played with the header data, debugged the code (I do set the correct content size); also search google and stackoverflow for any hints.

Below the code I use:

```
namespace RESTService.Controller
{
  public class TextToSpeechController : ApiController
  {
    [HttpGet, ActionName("Get")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string text)
    {
      HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      MemoryStream memoryStream = new TTS.TTS().ToWavStream(text);
      HttpContent content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);

      content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "audio/wav");
      content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", memoryStream.Length.ToString());

      response.Content = content;

      return response;
    }
  }
}
```

```
namespace RESTService
{
  public class Service
  {
    public void Run()
    {
      var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("TTS", "{controller}/{text}", 
        new[] { "RESTService.Controller" });

      using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
      {
        server.OpenAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any hint on what I need to change to get this to work would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I was able to get this to work if I use a byte array instead of a stream:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;

namespace RESTService.Controller
{
  public class TextToSpeechController : ApiController
  {
    [HttpGet, ActionName("Get")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string text)
    {
      HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      MemoryStream memoryStream = new TTS.TTS().ToWavStream(text);
      HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());

      content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/wav");
      content.Headers.ContentRange = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentRangeHeaderValue(memoryStream.Length);
      content.Headers.ContentLength = memoryStream.Length;

      response.Content = content;

      return response;
    }
  }
}
```